# show $\int_{0}^1 x^{ax-a} \ dx$ diverges.

Tags: calculus

Note that $a\in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$.

work:

When $a=1$, i was able to form an inequality of the type $\frac{c}{x} \leq x^{x-1}$, where $c=\mathrm{min}\  x^x$. However, this approach failed for larger $a$.  I also tried looking at the taylor series but I'm not sure how to use that to show that the integral diverges.

Comment: Range of $a$? All $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: i Should say $a\in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $\lim_{x \to 0}x^x=1$ and $x^{ax}$ is bounded away from $0$ on the interval. Hence the integral diverges if $a \geq 1$.

Comment: why does the boundedness imply divergence?

Comment: $x^{ax-a} \geqslant cx^{-a}$ with $c > 0$ and the integral of $x^{-a}$ diverges if $a \geqslant 1$

Comment: ah....i kept thinking $1/x^p$ diverges (wrongly associating it with the $p$ series) without actually carrying out the integration....

Comment: Correct.  We are concerned with the behavior near $x=0$ here rather than infinity.